# Regular expression 3

Tags: regex

What would be the regular expression for all stirngs w over the alphabet [a,b] such that w has three consecutive a's. I came up with (aaab|b)* aaa(b|baaa)* but not certain. Thanks!

Some valid match would be baaabbb, aaabaaa bbaaabaaa

Comment: Some examples of valid match would be helpful.

Comment: are `abaaa` and `aaa` also valid?

Comment: abaaa would not be valid because it has to be 3 consecutive a's. But aaa would!

Comment: When doesn't `abaaa` contain 3 adjacent `a`'s :S ...? "ab`aaa`"

Comment: @JarimSeo: in other words less than 3 `a`'s are not allowed and more than 3 `a`'s are not allowed too except the multiple of 3 `a`'s isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The regex to match three adjacent `a`s is somewhat complex. Just kidding ;) It's

```
aaa
```

That's right. Match against `aaa` returns `true` if there are 3 a's in a row.

**Edit:**

Noticed Casimir comment - if there can't be more than 3 in a row, use

```
(?<!a)aaa(?!a)
```

if look-behinds are suported.

Otherwise you could try

```
(^|[^a])aaa(?!a)
```

Regards